# Run script only on main jelastic node

Tags: jelastic

Is there a way to determinate that this node.js node is main using environment variables?

server.js

```
if (process.env === 'main') runSmth()
```

In [docs](https://docs.jelastic.com/environment-variables/) i found only:

```
MASTER_ID - A unique node identifier of a master node within a layer.
```

But i suppose it's the same for every node. And i did not found node_if variable :(

Answer (score 1):

Example of bash condition to find out if script is running on the master node:

```
[[ $(hostname -s) == $MASTER_HOST* ]] && { 
  echo "It's the MASTER"; 
} || { 
  echo "It's NOT the MASTER"; 
}
```